# highstock tough scrolling

Tags: highcharts

When using touch devices, it is neseccary to scroll the page with a finger, it captures all the touch events to prevent scrolling. is there a hack to get this to work with highstock like there is for highcharts
[Highcharts Touch Hack](https://gist.github.com/skarface/2994906)

Comment: In next release, highcharts will be more user friendly for touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Pointer's pinch method like this:

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Pointer.prototype, 'pinch', function pinch(proceed, e) {
if (e.touches.length === 1 && e.type === 'touchmove') {
  this.chart.pan(e, this.chart.options.panning)
} else {
  proceed.call(this, e)
  if (e.type === 'touchstart') {
    this.chart.mouseDownX = this.pinchDown[0].chartX
    this.chart.mouseDownY = this.pinchDown[0].chartY
  }
}
})
```